# Delete account in firebase in objective c

Tags: swift, objective-c, firebase-authentication

AppStore rejected my App and asked me to provide a deleted account when I have account creation. I am using Sign in with Apple, Google, and Email.

To delete the account I followed the documents in firebase. But then received an error FIRAuthErrorCodeRequiresRecentLogin

> "Delete account error This operation is sensitive and requires recent
> authentication. Log in again before retrying this request."

```
FIRUser* user = [ [ FIRAuth auth ] currentUser ];

[ user deleteWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    
    if( error )
    {
        // An error happened.
        if( error.code == FIRAuthErrorCodeRequiresRecentLogin)
        {
             return;
        }
     }
  }
```

Upon checking the error I understand that I need to reauthenticate and delete the account. After signing in it gives me 5 minutes that I can delete my account.

What I did is when I got the error FIRAuthErrorCodeRequiresRecentLogin, I will request the user to Sign out and Sign in again, then delete the account. This works but this is not the right way I think. No one will want to relog again by signing out.

Can someone help me with how I can reauthenticate by getting the credential that was signed by google, apple, and email?

```
            // How to get a credential when I am already signed in via google, apple, or email?
            FIRAuthCredential* credential;
            
            NSLog( @"Delete account error %@", error.localizedDescription );
            
            [[FIRAuth auth].currentUser reauthenticateWithCredential:credential completion:^(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable authResult, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                
                NSLog( @"Error %@", error);
            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to sign the user out in order to reauthenticate them. Instead you can call the `reauthenticate` method (as shown in the documentation on [reauthenticating the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user)) while they are still signed in.

Comment: What do I do to get the credential? Do we just pass nil? It gives me exception.

Comment: Getting the credential depends on the provider. For example for Google sign-in see step 4 here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin#2_implement_google_sign-in